# Comparison Operator Vs. Assignment Operator In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a piece of code from a simple Bookmarker App I made. I am kind of confused about something here.
Look at the 3rd line of the code. Isn't there supposed to be `==` instead of `=` after `classname`?
Because `=` is an assignment operator. What I need is `true` which `==` or `===` should give and it indeed does from the `console.log`.

However when I use `===` inside the `if` statement the function no longer works. But it works with the `=` which is not making any sense to me. It would be great if someone could clarify what's the problem here.

If anyone would like to check the full code including the HTML and CSS, here it is: https://github.com/magnetickode/Bookmarking-App

```
document.querySelector('.bookmarks').addEventListener('click', deleteBookmark);

function deleteBookmark(e) {

  if (e.target.className = 'delete') {

    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);

    console.log(e.target.className === 'delete');
    //console.log(e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent);

    for (let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
      if (bookmarks[i].name === e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent) {
        bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: asignment operator always returns `true` in an `if` statement ... why the others do not work is not clear from this fragment of code you provided

Comment: what is e.target.className?

Comment: @MichelEngelen, no, if you assign a falsy value, then it returns the falsy value for the check.

Comment: @xianshenglu ... I wanted to ask this as well ... it seems as if he is selecting by one class and adds an eventlistener depending on this ... so from my point of view the `e.target.className` of each of these elements should be at least `bookmarks delete` and therefore wpould never be `true` by checking only for one of the classNames

Comment: @NinaScholz ok, you are right ... I should have been more clear with this one, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You can check the full code from the link provided.

Comment: e.target.className is a delete button that only has 'delete' as a class.

Comment: it works fine with e.target.classList.contains('delete') as well.

Comment: is this your delete button ?<button class="btn delete">Delete</button>,obviously,it's className==='btn delete'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
if (e.target.className = 'delete') {
```

to

```
if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
```

Comment: I already did that before. Getting functionality is not the problem. I'm confused about why className === 'delete' doesn't work when it should.

Comment: @MagneticKode,        console.log(e.target.className === 'delete'); is this true or false?and what is the output of e.target.className

Comment: @MagneticKode,for what i have seen,your code:class="btn delete" means e.target.className==="btn delete" not "delete",is it ?

Comment: @MagneticKode,I see your button with class="btn delete",so  e.target.className != 'delete'

Comment: Lol damn can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing it out. It's all cleared now.

Comment: @MagneticKode did it return true when you had `e.target.className = 'delete'` as `if` condition? That would explain why, because you were setting `className` to `'delete'` this way and would then become `true` in your `console.log`

Comment: @MichelEngelen yap that's right. Now I understand why the console.log was returning true. I feel like such a noob for getting confused with all these.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `if` statement we should use anything, which converts to `boolean`, so, as you mentioned, simple assignment doesn't make sense, because it always returns `true`. `e.target.className` contains all classes of the element, so you can't just do `e.target.className == 'delete'` or `e.target.className === 'delete'` if there is more than one class, because strings will not be equal (`"q w e"` includes `"q"`, but `"q"` isn't equal to `"q w e"`). I see, you're using ES6, so you can do `e.target.className.includes('delete')`, it checks, does the element contain class `delete`, (for more info about `includes` method for strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). It is also possible to use [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) like `element.className.indexOf('class') !== -1` to test for the existence of a class (or `=== -1` to test for it's absence).

And here is the example:

```js
const bookmarks = document.querySelectorAll('.bookmarks');
for (let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
  bookmarks[i].addEventListener('click', deleteBookmark);
}

function deleteBookmark(e) {
  alert("Target contains 'delete' class? " + e.target.className.includes('delete').toString().toUpperCase());
  /*if (e.target.className.includes('delete')) {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);

    for (let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
      if (bookmarks[i].name ===e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent) {
        bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }*/
}
```

```html
<div class="bookmarks delete">CLICK (contains "delete" class)</div>
<div class="bookmarks">CLICK (doesn't contain "delete" class)</div>
```

Comment: The includes method does work. But I still don't get why className == doesn't work although there is only one class on the e.target I'm aiming for.

Comment: @MagneticKode, not really, there are at leas two, because you use `document.querySelector('.bookmarks')` (it's the first class), and then you check for `delete` class existence (it's the second).