# JS script that compares two paswords isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating and registration form for my website and i'm trying to add a JS script, which compares two password inputs ( password and repeat password) and then shows a message " passwords are not the same". Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">

        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: center; font-size: 25px; line-height: 20px">Zarejestruj sie ! </h5>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>New Login</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="your login">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>New password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pas1" placeholder="password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Repeat password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pas2" placeholder="password">
              </div>
              <p id="alert"></p>
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Funkcja()">Zarejestruj konto</button>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Underneath that hmtl code i've placed this JS script:

```
<script>
function Chceck() {
    var x, y, text;

    // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById("pas1").value;
    y = document.getElementById("pas2").value;

    // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
    if (x = y) {
    text= "";

    } else {
        text = "Hasla nie sa takie same";
    }
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Can somebody help me make it work?

Comment: = is assignment, == or === is comparison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison Operator Vs. Assignment Operator In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850308/comparison-operator-vs-assignment-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` or `===` for comparison of two variables and `=` for assignment:

```
if (x == y) { // change this line to be 'x == y' from 'x = y' 
    text= "";
} else {
    text = "Hasla nie sa takie same";
}
```

You can think of `==` as being less 'strict' than `===`

For example `1 == true` is a `true` statement, but  `1 === true` is a `false` statement

Comment: Additionally, and perhaps more appropriately, you can think of `==` as checking that the `values` are equal irrespective of the data type (e.g. `2 == '2'`) i.e. `int 2` is the same as `string 2`; while you can think of `===` as checking for both `value` and `type` equality

Comment: The truth is, `==` meaning coercion is allow before comparison while `===` doesnt allow

Answer (score 0):

`x = y` is assigning `y`'s value to `x` so it will always be true. You should use `x==y` (or `x====y`) for comparisons. You should use `===` to not coerce type conversion when comparing variables. For example, if you compare `1=="1"`, it will be true, but `1==="1"` will be false. The following code should work:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">

        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: center; font-size: 25px; line-height: 20px">Zarejestruj sie ! </h5>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>New Login</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="your login">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>New password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pas1" placeholder="password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Repeat password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pas2" placeholder="password">
              </div>
              <p id="alert"></p>
            </form>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Chceck(event)">Zarejestruj konto</button>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
     function Chceck(event) {
     var x, y, text;

     // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
      x = document.getElementById("pas1").value;
     y = document.getElementById("pas2").value;
     //check if x and y are both not empty
     if(x.trim().length&&y.trim().length){
          if (x == y) {
           text= "";
          } else {
            text = "Hasla nie sa takie same";
            event.preventDefault();//prevent default submission of form
          }
          document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "<b style='color: red;'>"+text+"</b>";
       }   else {
          event.preventDefault();//prevent default submission of form
         document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "<b style='color: red;'>Password can not be empty!</b>";
           }
       }
     </script>
```

Comment: I had never heard of `x====y` :)

Comment: `x = y` is assigning x to y? whatttttt?

Comment: @Isaac Thanks for telling me. I corrected the typo.